# Call class using EF Core from Layout view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have a Layout that is calling an static class to retrieve some information from the database, but I'm migrating the project to use entity framework core, but you know that I need to pass an instance parameter to EF Core to instantiate it now, so I have changed the static class to non static but of course now it's complaining because I'm calling that class from the Layout with static signature, and to call it from the Layout I need to pass that instance parameter, so I would need to create a class in the Layout to retrieve it? I don't think I would do that.. What can I do? Any suggestion is welcome.

This is the class(I've changed to an instance class in order to have an instance constructor but now I need to change the signature from the Layout view to call it as an instance class with the instance parameter...):

```
  public class LocationLookup
    {
       DataContext context;
        public LocationLookup(IOptions<DBConnection> connectionsAccessor)
        {
            context = new DataContext(connectionsAccessor);
        }

        public static List<MyLocations> GetLocations()
        {            
            var locations = context.MyLocations.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
            return locations;
        }
    }
```

And this is how I'm currently calling the method(I need to change this to call it as an instance class but how can I retrieve the `connectionsAccessor` instance parameter? I'm in the `Layout.cshtml` view)

```
 @{                                         
      var locations = LocationLookup.GetLocations();
  }
```

Any suggestion of a better approach is welcome

Comment: Presuming you have a controller action, can you not do it in the controller and set ViewBag.Locations?

Comment: Absolutely remove that `static DataContext`: context should always be an instance and created by the DI engine on every request.

Comment: @AntDC I've think about that too but I'm not sure it's the better approach, in that case I need to make sure to call that controller action in the startup and create the ViewBag.Locations in there

Comment: Why on startup? Please note that you can [inject dependencies in Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection) like you do on controllers.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma the link you shared is great :). I didn't now about the `@inject` syntax to inject dependencies in views. Please put it as an answer so i can give you the point and select it as the answer thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to inject a service directly in the view.

Start by turning your `LocationLookup` into a service with direct dependency on your `DbContext`:

```
public class LocationLookupService
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public LocationLookupService(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<MyLocations> GetLocations()
    {            
        var locations = _context.MyLocations.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
        return locations;
    }
}
```

Register it in the DI engine:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<DataContext>( <!-- your code --> );
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddScoped<LocationLookupService>();
}
```

And now you are ready to inject it inside your views:

```
@inject LocationLookupService LocationLookup

@{
    var locations = LocationLookup.GetLocations();
}
```